# User and Score models

Tags: python, template, django

I have a couple of models - `User` & `Score`. I am displaying data from those models to my template. Data from `Score` is filtered based on data from `User`. I am using nested `for` loops and an `if` condition within the template to get my desired result. However, I want to know if there is a better way of coming up with the same result because once the data gets huge by number, the nested for loop is going to use up a lot of time and resource.

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Score(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def Home(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    scores = Score.objects.all()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'users': users, 'scores': scores})
```

**home.html (template)**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for score in scores %}
    {% if score.user == user %} {{ user }} -- {{ score.subject }} -- {{ score.score }} <br>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Result**

> ```
> Michel -- Physics -- 80 
> Michel -- Chemistry -- 90 
> Zarif -- Physics -- 100 
> Zarif -- Biology -- 80
> ```

This question is a simplified version of [this (Django ORM usage in template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680936/django-orm-usage-in-template). If you can, maybe answer over there too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop seems to serve the purpose of grouping the output by user.
Since `Score` has a link to `User`,
you can achieve the same effect by getting the scores ordered by the user field, like this:

```
def Home(request):
    scores = Score.objects.order_by('user')
    return render(request, "home.html", {'scores': scores})
```

And then in the template you can eliminate one `for` and one `if`:

```
{% for score in scores %}
{{ score.user }} -- {{ score.subject }} -- {{ score.score }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```